# sharding a neo4j graph, min-cut

Tags: neo4j, graph-theory

I've heard of a max flow min cut method for sharding or segmenting a graph database.  Does someone have a sample cypher query that can do that say against the movielens dataset?  Basically I want to segment users into different shards/clusters based on what they like so maybe the min cuts can naturally find clusters of users around the genres say Horror, Drama, or maybe it will create non-intuitive clusters/segments like hipster/romantics and conservative/comedy/horror groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my short answer is no, sorry I don't know how you would express that.

my longer answer is even if this were possible - which it very well may be - I would advise against it.

multiple algorithms 'do' [min-cut max-flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem), these will all have different performance characteristics and, because clustering is computationally expensive, I'd guess you want control over the specific algorithm implementation used.
Cypher is a declarative language, you specify ***what*** you're looking for but not ***how*** to do it, and it will be difficult to specify such a complex problem in a way that the Cypher engine can figure out what you're trying to do. that will make it hard for Cypher (or any declarative language engine) to produce an efficient query plan.

my suggestion is find the specific algorithm you wish to use and implement it using the [Neo4j Java API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded.html).
if you're running Neo4j in embedded mode you're done at that point. if you're running Neo4j server you'll then just have to run that code as an [Unmanaged Server Extension](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html)

AFAIK you're after 'Community Detection' algorithms. There are non-overlapping (communities do not overlap) and overlapping variants, where non-overlapping is generally easier to implement and understand. Common algorithms are:

- Non-overlapping: [Louvain](http://perso.uclouvain.be/vincent.blondel/research/louvain.html)
- Overlapping: Label Propagation Algorithm (LPA) (typically non-overlapping, but there are extensions to make it overlapping)

Here are a few C++ code examples for the algorithms: [Louvain, Oslom (overlapping), LPA (non-overlapping), and Infomap)](https://sites.google.com/site/andrealancichinetti/software)

And if you want bleeding edge I was recommended the SCD algorithm

- Academic paper: ["High Quality, Scalable and Parallel Community Detection for Large Real Graphs"](http://www.dama.upc.edu/publications/fp546prat.pdf)
- C++ [implementation](https://github.com/DAMA-UPC/SCD)